# How do I use memtest86+'s "badram" output with GRUB2?

Tags: memory, grub2

So after a while of things randomly crashing, I let memtest86+ run overnight, and it found errors.

I enabled the "badram" error output, but every few seconds it shows me a differing selection of memory locations:

```
badram=0x14000000,0xfc000800,0x11000000,0xf9000000,0x00000000,0xe2000000,
       0x12000000,0xfb000000,0x10000000,0xf8003000,0x0a000000,0xea000000,
       0x20000000,0xe0000000,0x40000000,0xe0000000,0x60000000,0xf0000000,
       0x70000000,0xf8000000
badram=0x14000000,0xfc000800,0x11000000,0xf9000000,0x00000000,0xe2000000,
       0x12000000,0xfb000000,0x10000000,0xf8003000,0x0a000000,0xea000000,
       0x20000000,0xe0000000,0x40000000,0xc0000000
```

My understanding is that I should be able to take that output and put it into GRUB2's configuration.  I see the configuration option; I know where to put it.  But... there are two different badram values reported?  Which do I use?  Obviously I don't understand the output.

I will buy new RAM, but would still like to do this as a temporary solution.

(I am running Ubuntu 12.10 BTW.)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  Apparently all the errors were caused by a bug in the version of memtest86+ that ships with Ubuntu 12.10 anyway.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/1071209

I made a bootable USB with the live CD from Ubuntu 12.04 and am scanning again.  Thus far no errors.